# how to set time out at socket read in php

Tags: php, sockets

I am reading a socket using do-while loop at server side.

```
<?php
$host = "192.168.1.99";
$port = 3501;
set_time_limit(0);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
stream_set_timeout($spawn ,0 ,1000);
do
{
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message : ".$input;
flush(); @ob_flush();
$output = strrev($input) . "\n";
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
sleep(3);
}
while ($input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n"));
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

In this case, it is always running in a loop and waiting for incoming data.
How to stop the loop if no data received from client within a minute? I cant close the socket from client side.

Comment: Try to use [stream_set_timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php)

Comment: where should i try.. i tried before reading, i got an error, i have given the same resource whatever used to read. stream_set_timeout(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource.

Comment: I tried stream_set_timeout ($socket ,0 ,500); or stream_set_timeout ($spawn ,0 ,500);

Comment: Show your full code (with $spawn creation)

Comment: I have updated in the question..